# Redirecionar Subdomínio para outro servidor

Tags: servidor, domínio, cpanel, virtualhost

Estou usando o *cPanel* e consigo redirecionar o subdominio `exemplo.dominio.com.br` para outro servidor usando o registro A e o *IP* do novo servidor, mas como faço pra esse subdomínio ser acessível também usando www ou sem www?

Seria nas configurações de redirecionamento ou no *htaccess* do novo servidor?

Comment: Mas `www` já é um subdomínio. Alguém iria acessar `www.exemplo.dominio.com.br`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não conheço muito bem CPanel, mas sei que você consegue realizar esse acesso com www e sem www alterando seu vhost, apontando o vhost com www e sem www para a mesma pasta, por exemplo:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dominio.com.br
    ServerName www.dominio.com.br
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dominio.com.br
    ServerName dominio.com.br
</VirtualHost>
```